# Surround FOR with an IF or more complex FOR condition?

Tags: php

I came across this trivial dilemma (a oxymoron for you).

1.

```
if(condition1) {
 for(int i = 0;condition2 ;i++){...}
}
```

2.

```
for(int i = 0; condition1 && condition2; i++){...}
```

Which is more good taste programming?

I would say 1 is more efficient and 2 more elegant.

What you think?

Edit: People downvoting can you please point what's wrong?

Comment: Aren't they the same? The for simply didn't start if `exampleArray.length` were 0. The first solution is easier to read in my opinion, but not more efficient

Comment: Yes, They are exactly the same. My question is more about the conding style. This kind of decision may have big impact in more complex examples.

Comment: My issue here is that condition1 may not have much to do with the FOR condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 not elegant imo, it's might be confusing in complex cases

in for statement you have to control loop, not mix in some other conditions

p/s i know is just opinion, but a haven't enough rep for commenting)